# SignalR and AzureAD authentication : loose websocket in favor of long polling

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, signalr, azure-ad-msal

Our **Asp.net core/React** application used **SignalR** with good performance.
We added an authentication, made client side (React), with **msal**.
Since I added the AzureAD authentication, the negotiation of SignalR connection between client and server goes from **WebSockets** -> **ServerSideEvents** -> **Long polling**
With **Long polling** the performance degrades enormously.

[image: Connection phase]

In connection phase, there is a 401, despite the Jwt being passed both as query string and header

Here is the client code, passing the token:

```
let optimizerConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("/hubpath", 
            { 
            accessTokenFactory: () => getRawJwtToken() },
            false, // skipNegotiation
             HttpTransportType.WebSockets //transport
             )
  .withAutomaticReconnect()
  .configureLogging(LogLevel.Trace)
  .build()
```

Here is the the Hub with required authentication (the identity information, claims,...) goes to the server with the **[Authorize]** attribute. But authentication makes to use long polling, and is so slow:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes=JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Roles="Optimizer")]
public class SomeHub : Hub, ISomeHub { ...}
```

Here is the configuration of the identity server side:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
      .Build();
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(configuration);
```

I read all the posts I found about the subject, sometimes with Jwt authentication (not **AzureAD**).
Some posts mention an **OnMessageReceived** method.
I implemented **OnMessageReceived**, but it is not called:

```
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(ConfigureJwtBearerOptions,
                                      ConfigureMicrosoftIdentityOptions,
                                      jwtBearerScheme: "Bearer",
                                      subscribeToJwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents: true);

private static void ConfigureMicrosoftIdentityOptions(MicrosoftIdentityOptions options)
{
  options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
  options.ClientId = "myClientIdGuid";
  options.Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/myInstanceGuid";
}
private static void ConfigureJwtBearerOptions(JwtBearerOptions options)
{
  options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
  {
    OnChallenge = OnChallenge,
    OnTokenValidated = OnTokenValidated,
    OnAuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
    OnForbidden = OnForbidden,
    OnMessageReceived = context =>
    {
      var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
      // If the request is for our hub...
      var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
          (path.StartsWithSegments(SomeHub.Path)))
      {
        // Read the token out of the query string
        context.Token = accessToken;
      }
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
  };
}
```

If anybody has a clue, thank you

Comment: [Following the official doc, and test it in my local, it works fine.](https://codeshare.io/eVg0nL)

Comment: And what is `jwtBearerScheme` in your code, I can't reproduce it.

Comment: jwtBearerScheme is the name of the third parameter of AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi. It is Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi (Microsoft.Identity.Web 2.13.3.0).

Comment: Thank you very much Jason  for helping, I haven't much time now but I'll try to reproduce the steps as soon as possible

Comment: @Jason, I couldn't get your exemple to work. I had troubles setting the options.Authority value. Neither https://localhost:5001, neither https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenantguid worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working !
Even if I didn't get the OnMessageReceived to be called.

A modification was adding a service - likely to be closely equivalent to ****AddAuthentication()**** + ****AddMicrosoftIdentityWeabApi()****

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(configuration, "AzureAd");
```

And then add a custom middleware before ****UseAuthentication()****

```
  app.UseMiddleware<AccessTokenMiddleware>();
  app.UseAuthentication();
```

The middleware puts the query string parameter in the headers

```
public class AccessTokenMiddleware
{
  private readonly RequestDelegate next;
  public AccessTokenMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
  {
    this.next = next;
  }
  public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
  {
    var request = httpContext.Request;
    // Web sockets cannot pass headers so the access token must be taken from query param and
    // added to the header before authentication middleware runs
    if (request.Path.StartsWithSegments(SomeHub.Path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
        request.Query.TryGetValue("access_token", out var accessToken))
      request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
    await next(httpContext);
  }
}
```